I walk 3 km every day
This sentence in English means I walk a distance every day for exercising and keeping my body fit. How can I translate it to German? The possibilities I see:

Ich laufe jeden Tag 3 km  (ambiguous if I walk or run)
Ich gehe jeden Tag 3 km zu Fuß  (not sure "zu Fuß gehen" can be used without a target location)
Ich gehe jeden Tag 3 km spazieren (but spazieren can only be used for leisure and walking without a goal)


"ambiguous if I walk or run" No, not in this sentence. Laufen can sometimes mean walking if the emphasis is on not driving or using public transport, but in the context of exercise Laufen means running.

I think the simplest is:
Ich gehe jeden Tag 3 km.

You can add "zu Fuß", if you want to emphasize, but "gehen" usually means already "to walk".
I personally would emphasise the "every day" and write it at the start:
Jeden Tag gehe ich 3 km.


Alle 3 Antworten sind im Deutschen, je nach dem, was ausgedrückt werden soll, möglich und üblich.


Ich laufe jeden Tag 3 km (ambiguous if I walk or run)


Richtig - das kann mehr in Richtung spazieren gehen sein, es kann joggen sein, es kann ambitioniertes Laufen auf Zeit sein, etwa das Training eines Olympioniken, der auf die 3km-Strecke abzielt.


Ich gehe jeden Tag 3 km zu Fuß (not sure "zu Fuß gehen" can be used without a target location)


Das geht ohne Ziel aber passt nicht für Joggen und Laufen. Es könnte Training sein (Gehen als Sport), kontemplatives Gehen zur Entspannung aber auch der Weg zur Arbeit/Schule.


Ich gehe jeden Tag 3 km spazieren (but spazieren can only be used for leisure and walking without a goal)


Auch richtig. Die Geschwindigkeit ist eher gemütlich; wenn es überhaupt ein Ziel gibt (Montags zum Bergcafé, Dienstags zum Parkcafé, ...) spielt dieses nur eine Hauptrolle.
Ganz vage bzgl. der Geschwindigkeit (Laufen, Gehen, Rennen) wäre:

Ich mache jeden Tag 3 km.

Das ist jedoch so vage, dass auch Schwimmen oder Radfahren gemeint sein könnten und auch ziemlich informell (Umgangssprache).

Es gibt einen Unterschied zwinschen Laufen und "Gehen als Sport" ? Bedeutet nicht beides "to run"? Also bedeutet "passt nicht für Joggen und Laufen" dass es in diesem Zusammenhang nie verwendet werden kann oder dass die Geschwindigkeit nicht eindeutig ist?

@AlanEvangelista: Die Details kennt sicher Wikipedia unter "Gehen", ich meine da muss permanent (mindestens) ein Fuß den Boden berühren. Beim Laufen sind auch kurz beide i.d. Luft. Außerhalb des Sports kann "Laufen", abhängig vom Kontext, aber auch Gehen bedeuten. "Sie sind den ganzen Weg vom Wannsee gelaufen" wird meist nicht heißen, dass sie gerannt sind. To run and to go von der Geschwindigkeit - darüber aber nicht präzise voneinander abgrenzbar.
